# switch case in java by strings < 1.7

Tags: java, javascript, switch-statement

```
function checkValue(value) {
    if (value === null || value === undefined || value === '') {
        return '-';
    } else {
        switch (value) {
        case true:
            return 'Yes';
            break;
        case false:
            return 'No';
            break;
        default:
            return value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the switch case by string is only available > 1.7. Is there anyway i can convert this piece of code in java without using traditional `if/else`. This piece of code is written in `JavaScript`.

Comment: I would prefer if/else, but you can create and use enum.

Comment: You can use enums to do switch
Represent the Strings as enums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Enum for that like this:

```
enum MyEnum {

    A1, A2, A3;

}

String val = "myVal"; // your input

MyEnum enumVal;
try {
    enumVal = MyEnum(val);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    enumVal = null;
}

switch (enumVal) {

    case A1: 
        doSomething();
        break;

    case A2: 
        doOtherStuff();
        break;

    default: 
        doDefault();
        break;

}
```

If you think the try block is too ugly you can use [EnumUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html) from [apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), that will do the stuff for you, you just need to change this:

```
MyEnum enumVal;
try {
    enumVal = MyEnum(val);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    enumVal = null;
}
```

with this:

```
MyEnum enumVal = EnumUtils.getEnum(MyEnum.class, val);
```

**EDIT**

For the case you wanna filter just boolean values that aren't string, you could do something like:

```
Object input = "MyString";

if (input == Boolean.TRUE) {
    return "Yes";
} else if (input == Boolean.FALSE) {
    return "No";
} else {
    return input;
}
```

If they are strings, you need to compare string itself like:

```
if ("true".equals(input)) {
    return "Yes";
} else if ("false".equals(input)) {
    return "No";
} else {
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Can't we have boolean values in enum private enum MyEnum {
  true, false
 }

Comment: you need it for true / false? In this case is easier (and that is exactly they are therefore) to use a `if` statement and `Boolean.parseBoolean(String value)` that will return `true` when `String` is `.equals` to `"true"` and `false` otherwise.

Comment: yes, i need it for true/false... i am getting from the service as true or false and i need to display "yes" or "no" in front end

Comment: and in fact `"true"` and `"false"` cannot be used as a valid value for your enum, but java enum should be uppercase written, meaning `TRUE` and `FALSE`, and this is allowed, but you need to upper the string before perform the valueOf() (if you wanna go with the enum approach)

Answer (score 6):

Use enum instead  as <1.7 switch on strings wont support

```
    private enum MyEnum {
        a, b, c, d;
    }

    String val; // input
    MyEnum mye = MyEnum.valueOf(val);

    switch (mye) {
        case a:
            return something;
        case carrot:
            return something;
        ..
    }
```

P.S :pseudo code. IDE not in hand .Sorry.

Comment: in order to cover `default` case you can perform valueOf inside a try catch assigning `null` to it when exception or using `EnumUtils` from apache commons to get the enum value without throwing exception and then perform the switch-case.

Comment: There is actually much more hidden behind the JavaScript code than just the switch case (type checking, implicit type casting etc.). The switch case itself is using only boolean conditions and can be implemented in Java just like that as well without using enums.

Comment: @JavaMentor You are correct.But I am extreamly sorry for not providing the full fledged code,as i am unable.